# Python Peewee EXISTS Subquery not working as expected

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am using the peewee ORM for a python application and I am trying to write code to fetch batches of records from a SQLite database. I have a subquery that seems to work by itself but when added to an update query the `fn.EXISTS(sub_query)` seems to have no effect as every record in the database is updated.

Note: I am using the APSW extension for peewee.

```
def batch_logic(self, id_1, path_1, batch_size=1000, **kwargs):
    sub_query = (self.select(ModelClass.granule_id).distinct().where(
        (ModelClass.status == 'old_status') &
        (ModelClass.collection_id == collection_id) &
        (ModelClass.name.contains(provider_path))
    ).order_by(ModelClass.discovered_date.asc()).limit(batch_size)).limit(batch_size))
    print(f'len(sub_query): {len(sub_query)}')
    fb_st_2 = time.time()
    updated_records= list(
        (self.update(status='new_status').where(fn.EXISTS(sub_query)).returning(ModelClass))
    )
    print(f'update {len(updated_records)}: {time.time() - fb_st_2}')

    db.close()
    return updated_records
```

Below is output from testing locally:

```
id_1: id_1_1676475997_PQXYEQGJWR
len(sub_query): 2
update 20000: 1.0583274364471436
fetch_batch 20000: 1.1167597770690918
count_things 0: 0.02147078514099121
processed_things: 20000
```

The subquery is correctly returning `2` but the update query `where(fn.EXISTS(sub_query))` seems to be ignored. Have I made a mistake in my understanding of how this works?

Edit 1: I believe `GROUP BY` is needed as rows can have the same `granule_id` and I need to fetch rows up to `batch_size` `granule_id`s

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of UPDATE...WHERE EXISTS is incorrect or inappropriate here. This may work better for you:

```
# Unsure why you have a GROUP BY with no aggregation, that seems
# incorrect possibly, so I've removed it.
sub_query = (self.select(ModelClass.id)
             .where(
                (ModelClass.status == 'old_status') &
                (ModelClass.collection_id == id_1) &
                (ModelClass.name.contains(path_1)))
             .order_by(ModelClass.discovered_date.asc())
             .limit(batch_size))

update = (self.update(status='new_status')
          .where(self.id.in_(sub_query))
          .returning(ModelClass))
cursor = update.execute()  # It's good to explicitly execute().
updated_records = list(cursor)
```

The key idea, at any rate, is I'm correlating the update with the subquery.

Comment: I have updated the question. I believe `GROUP BY` or something similar is needed for what I'm trying to do. More specifically the changes you proposed limits the records returns to `batch_size`.

Comment: You also are applying a limit of batch_size in your question... Additionally you're (mis)using GROUP BY to achieve something like DISTINCT but I digress. Good luck.

Comment: The application of `batch_size` to the results of the sub query are intentional. I want to fetch `batch_size` unique `granule_is`s with the sub query and then update all rows that match those `granule_id`s which will likely be more than `batch_size`. 
I appreciate the distinct recommendation and have made the change but still to the same effect that `fn.EXISTS(...)` seems to ignore the results of the subquery.